# Output build duration as slack notification in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, slack, duration

I am running a Jenkins job and i am trying to output a BUILD DURATION in order to see how long it took to run the job. I am able to see the job name , builder number and the results but not the build duration.  My groovy script is as follow:

```
 post {
    success {
            slackSend channel: '#hscic-nts',
                color: 'good',
                message: "${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER} ${currentBuild.currentResult}: after ${env.BUILD_DURATION} \n"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According [docs](https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild), try `currentBuild.durationString` (or `currentBuild.duration` for milliseconds)

Comment: It seems to output the build duration which is working but then says and counting :

apple_definitions #55 SUCCESS: after 17 min and counting